# ggplot2 to plot time series by date using seperate date and variable dateframes r

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I'm trying to plot a time series. In one dataframe(y), I have 56 items in a column vector and I have a second dataframe (dates) with corresponding dates. I am trying to graph the time series as the values of y on the y-axis and the dates on the x axis. I have tried a number of things using ggplt2 geom_freqpoly but I can't figure it out.  I'm open to other methods besides ggplot and i can cbind date and y into one dateframe as well if it will make things easier.

Any advice?

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

N<- 500
M<-56

x<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=23,sd=3), N, M)
y <- colMeans(x,dim=1)

y <-as.data.frame(y)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-25"), by="days")
Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

a <- ggplot(date, aes(y))
a + geom_freqpoly()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are methods from several different packages.

**ggplot2**

The [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) package works the best on a data frame, so I would suggest you to create a data frame with your data. In addition, not sure why do you want to use `geom_freqpoly`. I think `geom_line` will work for time-series data.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

N<- 500
M<-56

x<- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=23,sd=3), N, M)
y <- colMeans(x,dim=1)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-25"), by="days")
Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

dat <- data.frame(Date = Date, y = y)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**ggpubr**

[ggpubr](/questions/tagged/ggpubr) is an extension of the [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) package. We can use `ggline` package to plot the data.

```
library(ggpubr)    
ggline(data = dat, x = "Date", y = "y")
```

[image]

**lattice**

We can also use the `xyplot` function from the [lattice](/questions/tagged/lattice) package.

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(y ~ Date, data = dat, type = "l")
```

[image]

**ggvis**

The [ggvis](/questions/tagged/ggvis) package, similar to [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot), uses grammar of graphics to create plots.

```
library(ggvis)

ggvis(dat, ~Date, ~y) %>% layer_lines()
```

[image]

**Base R**

We can also use the base R.

```
plot(dat$Date, dat$y, xaxt = "n", type = "l", xlab = "Date", ylab = "y")
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(min(dat$Date), max(dat$Date), by = "week"), format="%b %d")
```

[image]

**xts**

We can also convert the data frame to an [xts](/questions/tagged/xts) object and then plot it.

```
library(xts)

dat.ts <- xts(dat$y, order.by = dat$Date)
plot(dat.ts)
```

[image]

**PerformanceAnalytics**

We can also use the `chart.TimeSeries` from the [performanceanalytics](/questions/tagged/performanceanalytics) package to plot the `xts` package.

```
chart.TimeSeries(dat.ts)
```

[image]

**dygraphs**

The [dygraphs](/questions/tagged/dygraphs) package can create interactive time-series plot.

```
library(dygraphs)

dygraph(dat.ts)
```

[image]

**plotly**

We can also use [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) to create interactive plot.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x = ~dat$Date, y = ~dat$y, mode = 'lines')
```

[image]

We can also use [highcharter](/questions/tagged/highcharter) package to create interactive plot.

```
library(highcharter)

hchart(dat.ts)
```

[image]